# Как экранировать спецсимволы, например " \?", в строке URL из Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, url, replace

Есть строка, содержащая знак вопроса `?`, или несколько. Строка передается как параметр в URL. Знак вопроса нужно заменить на `%3f`. Как это сделать?

```java
String text = text.replaceAll("\?", "%3f");
```

Такой код дает ошибку:

```
Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
```

---

<sup>Перевод вопроса с enSO: [«Replace a question mark (?) with (\?)»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554749/replace-a-question-mark-with), не дословный, но очень похоже.</sup>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Поскольку знак вопроса "?" является спецсимволом в regexp, то экранировать его нужно не одним `"\"` слешем, а двумя `"\\"`

```
String text = text.replaceAll("\\?", "%3f");
```

Ну а в общем случае для разных спецсимволов у меня получилось вот что:

```
String text = text
            .replaceAll("%", "%25")   // Процент
            .replaceAll(" ", "%20")   // Пробел
            .replaceAll("\t", "%20")  // Табуляция (заменяем на пробел)
            .replaceAll("\n", "%20")  // Переход строки (заменяем на пробел)
            .replaceAll("\r", "%20")  // Возврат каретки (заменяем на пробел)
            .replaceAll("!", "%21")   // Восклицательный знак
            .replaceAll("\"", "%22")  // Двойная кавычка
            .replaceAll("#", "%23")   // Октоторп, решетка
            .replaceAll("\\$", "%24") // Знак доллара
            .replaceAll("&", "%26")   // Амперсанд
            .replaceAll("'", "%27")   // Одиночная кавычка
            .replaceAll("\\(", "%28") // Открывающаяся скобка
            .replaceAll("\\)", "%29") // Закрывающаяся скобка
            .replaceAll("\\*", "%2a") // Звездочка
            .replaceAll("\\+", "%2b") // Знак плюс
            .replaceAll(",", "%2c")   // Запятая
            .replaceAll("-", "%2d")   // Дефис
            .replaceAll("\\.", "%2e") // Точка
            .replaceAll("/", "%2f")   // Слеш, косая черта
            .replaceAll(":", "%3a")   // Двоеточие
            .replaceAll(";", "%3b")   // Точка с запятой
            .replaceAll("<", "%3c")   // Открывающаяся угловая скобка
            .replaceAll("=", "%3d")   // Знак равно
            .replaceAll(">", "%3e")   // Закрывающаяся угловая скобка
            .replaceAll("\\?", "%3f") // Вопросительный знак
            .replaceAll("@", "%40")   // At sign, по цене, собачка
            .replaceAll("\\[", "%5b") // Открывающаяся квадратная скобка
            .replaceAll("\\\\", "%5c") // Одиночный обратный слеш '\'
            .replaceAll("\\]", "%5d") // Закрывающаяся квадратная скобка
            .replaceAll("\\^", "%5e") // Циркумфлекс
            .replaceAll("_", "%5f")   // Нижнее подчеркивание
            .replaceAll("`", "%60")   // Гравис
            .replaceAll("\\{", "%7b") // Открывающаяся фигурная скобка
            .replaceAll("\\|", "%7c") // Вертикальная черта
            .replaceAll("\\}", "%7d") // Закрывающаяся фигурная скобка
            .replaceAll("~", "%7e");  // Тильда
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String shieldSpecialCharacters(String src) {
        return Pattern
            .compile("[^a-z0-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(src)
            .replaceAll(x -> "\\\\" + x.group());
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если кто сюда попал в поисках аналогичного вопроса для JavaSvript, то ответ:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent (str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```