# Как экранировать точку в методе split

Tags: регулярные-выражения, экранирование

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] words = line.split("\\s+|,\\s*");
```

Этим кодом я разделяю слова в строке, встречая символы запятой и пробела (просто из видео взято), а вот как экранировать точку не удалось найти

Comment: Точно так же, `line.split("\\.");`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как экранировать спецсимволы, например " \?", в строке URL из Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724868/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-url-%d0%b8%d0%b7-java)