# Как экранировать спецсимволы в json java

Tags: java, json, escape

Есть кусок кода, который различные данные преобразует в парамерты в виде json и отправляет в другую часть программы, где эти данные обрабатываются. Преобразование и обработка происходят образом, никак от меня независящем. Есть параметр name, который String. Если имя придет такое: "some Name", то проблемы не будет. Если же имя придет на подобии: some %20%name" то программа преобразует все это в такой вид: "some  %name"

Я не знаю, какие имена придут в прогу. Вопрос: есть ли какие библиотеки или еще чего, чтобы можно было экранировать\кодировать данный символ, или любой другой спецсимвол.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась не в json, а в декодировании URL запроса. Json прикреплялся к URL в виде параметров, и когда все это дело оборачивалось в URL все необходимые символы автоматически экранировались. НО СИМВОЛ %xy (xy- любые цифры) не экранируется средствами URL, поэтому эта строка "some %20%name" вначале становилась такой "some%20%20%name" а при парсинге URL заменяла 2 символа %20 на 2 пробела, что логично. Удалось решить проблему дописав свой класс для экранирования. Сделал по аналогии с
[Как экранировать спецсимволы, например " \?", в строке URL из Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724868/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%86%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-url-%d0%b8%d0%b7-java)